# アセンブリ言語のプログラムを教えてほしいです。できれば、プログラムを作ってほしいです。

Tags: assembly

以下のコードを参考にして、７個の数字を　A:１, B:２, C:１０, D:８, E:１０, F:５, G:６ として、A × B × C × D + E × F × G を計算するプログラムを教えてください。
結果は、４６０になります。

AxB+CxDを計算するプログラム

```
SAMPLE  START
    LD  GR0,A
    LD  GR1,B
    CALL    MUL
    ST  GR2,ANS
    LD  GR0,C
    LD  GR1,D
    CALL    MUL
    ADDA    GR2,ANS
    ST  GR2,ANS
    RET
MUL START
    PUSH    0,GR3
    LD  GR2,CONST0
    LD  GR3,CONST0
LOOP    CPA GR3,GR1
    JZE LABEL1
    ADDA    GR2,GR0
    ADDA    GR3,CONST1
    JUMP    LOOP
LABEL1  POP GR3
    RET
A   DC  4
B   DC  3
C   DC  2
D   DC  5
ANS DC  0
CONST0  DC  0
CONST1  DC  1
    END
```

A×BとC×Dはできたのですが、その２つをまたかけることが出来ません。
同様に、E×FとGをまた掛けることが出来ません。
その後の A×B×C×D　と　E×F×Gを足すことが出来るように教えてほしいです。

Comment: 今の書き方だと「代わりにプログラムを書いてください」のような印象を与えてしまうので、自分なりに考えて分からない部分をもう少し詳しく説明しておくと回答が付きやすいかもしれません。

Comment: A×BとC×Dはできたのですが、その２つをまたかけることが出来ません

Comment: 途中までであっても出来たところまでのソースと、試した結果がどうなったか、具体的にどの部分が分からないか等を質問記事に追記してみてください。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 例えばいきなりプログラムを組もうとするからどうするか分からなくなるので、計算式として手順を細かいステップに分けてみれば、糸口が見えてくるといったこともあるのでは？

Comment: 私はこの質問にクローズ票を投票します 。なぜなら... 「プログラムを作ってほしい」とは質問でもなんでもなく開発要求です。開発者を雇うべきです。

Comment: マルチポスト https://teratail.com/questions/gq7welo0qc7q54

Comment: アセンブリ言語には種類があるため、どんな CPU のためにどんなフォーマットでプログラミングなさろうとしているのかを知りたいです。パッと見 [CASL](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/CASL) かなと推測したのですが、実際のところ如何でしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

質問内容的に結果のプログラムソースをそのまま答えにするのは少しためらわれるので、考え方だけを示すとこんなステップになるでしょう。
`結果`・`答え`・`掛け算ルーチン`などが何かは、質問に提示されたプログラムソースから読み取ってください。

- `E`,`F`,`G`用の領域を追加定義し、`A`から`F`までを指定された値に設定しておく
- プログラムのメイン部分は以下のようにする

  - `A`と`B`をレジスタにロードして掛け算ルーチンを呼び出す
  - 掛け算の結果を答えに格納する
  - `C`と`D`をレジスタにロードして掛け算ルーチンを呼び出す
  - 掛け算の結果と答えをレジスタにロードして掛け算ルーチンを呼び出す
  - 掛け算の結果を答えに格納する
  - `E`と`F`をレジスタにロードして掛け算ルーチンを呼び出す
  - 掛け算の結果と`G`をレジスタにロードして掛け算ルーチンを呼び出す
  - 掛け算の結果に答えを加算する
  - 加算の結果を答えに格納する
  - 終了する

少し版数が古いようですが、以下にエミュレータがあるので簡単に確認できるでしょう。
[CASLⅡエミュレータ](https://www.chiba-fjb.ac.jp/fjb_labo/casl/casl2.cgi)

Comment: A×BとC×Dを掛けるときはサブルーチンを使えばいいですか？

Comment: はいそうです。メイン部分として書いている4ステップ目の処理ですね。

Answer (score 0):

これくらいなら逆アセンブリしてソースコードと見比べるのが良い気もしますが。